# Use a function that doesn't return value insider wordpress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, function, shortcode, jetpack

I am trying to use the jetpack sharing icons inside the shortcode which display the grid for the post..  But I have not been able to do so

Because sharing_display( '', true ) outputs the sharing icon , so I thought it is not displaying but even after using this `sharing_display( '', false )`  I am still not able to display icons

this is the code I am using..

```
if($loop->have_posts()): 
$html.='<div id="oj-blog" class="section blog-wrap">
          <div class="container">
            '.(($title?'<div class="title">
                <h2>'.$title.'</h2>
              </div>':'')).'

              <div class="row">';

while($loop->have_posts()):$loop->the_post();       

$html.='
          <div class="blog-single">

              <h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3>
              <p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>';
if ( function_exists( 'sharing_display' ) ) {
$html.=       sharing_display( '', false );
      }
$html.=       '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">Read More</a>
          </div>';

endwhile;    
endif;     
return $html;
```

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: Have you tried just sharing_display()